# Read a worksheet and write the content into a new one - Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

dear community

I was struggling with a piece of code in Python that could get data from a Excel worksheet by reading and after create a new sheet with that data. `
It's not just a copy of the file, because it allows to make something with data on the way before saving it in a new file.
I was reading a file, saving in a intermediary list and after trying to save in the new xls file.
It didn't work because of data type weren't talking with each other. And I got stuck.

I saw this code below from Python Engineering by Michael Zippo, that helped me.

```
# importing openpyxl module
import openpyxl as xl;

# opening the source excel file
filename ="C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\trading.xlsx"
wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]

# opening the destination excel file
filename1 ="C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\test.xlsx"
wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename1)
ws2 = wb2.active

# calculate total number of rows and
# columns in source excel file
mr = ws1.max_row
mc = ws1.max_column

# copying the cell values from source
# excel file to destination excel file

for i in range (1, mr + 1):
    for j in range (1, mc + 1):
        # reading cell value from source excel file
        c = ws1.cell(row = i, column = j)
        # writing the read value to destination excel file
        ws2.cell(row = i, column = j).value = c.value

# saving the destination excel file
wb2.save(str(filename1))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

After looking up to new thing about Michael Zippo, (https://python.engineering/python-how-to-copy-data-from-one-excel-sheet-to-another/).

I found a way to improve the read-write FOR loop above:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

wb1 = load_workbook('bank_statement.xlsx')
wb2 = Workbook()
sh1 = wb1.active
sh2 = wb2.active

for r in sh1.iter_rows():
    for c in r:
        sh2[c.coordinate]= c.value

wb2.save('bank_stat_improved.xlsx')
```

In the middle of the loop, you can do something with data and it will be a very useful code.